# Postgres inside docker; reload database / init script every time the container is started

Tags: postgresql, docker

Following [the offical postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), you can set up an entrypoint where you put your initilization scripts.

This works fine. For development/testing, I want a clean database on *every* container startup, not only on it's first.
All scripts inside the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are only run *once* (the first time the container is started).
Is there an easy way to execute the script every time the container is started via `docker-compose`?
I put `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` in front of every `CREATE TABLE`, so the `.sql` script will work even on a new startup.

Relevant part of the docker-compose if anyone needs that:

```
postgres-myname:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres-db
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgresql-config/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - my-network
```

Comment: You may want to specify an entrypoint script - here's an article which seems to describe your use case: https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data

Comment: If you run `docker-compose down -v`, Compose will clean up everything, including the local state for the database, and then when you run `up` again it will be starting from a clean slate.  I don't think there's a way to specify that you don't actually care about the default volumes.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "cycle script" for restarting, which should contain:

```sh
docker-compose rm -vs postgres-myname
docker volume prune -f --filter label=protgres-myname

docker-compose up -d
```

I recommend exploring `docker volume prune` before using it in a script.

I also recommend having a named volume mapped to postgres data directory (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) and removing the volume explicitly instead of pruning.

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
postgres-myname:
    volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    - pgdata
```

And then

```
docker volume rm -f "$(basename "`/bin/pwd`")_pgdata"
```